# Hashtable collision rehashing - how are values read?

Tags: c#, hashtable

I am trying to understand how Hashtables work in C#. I read the MSDN article and I understand that C# Hashtables use 'rehashing' for collisions, i.e. if I try to insert a key/value pair into the hashtable, if using HashFunction H1 results in a collision, then it will try HashFunction H2, H3, etc, until no collisions are found.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) quote:

> The Hashtable class uses a different technique referred to as
>   rehasing. (Some sources refer to rehashing as double hashing.)
>
> Rehashing works as follows: there is a set of hash different
>   functions, H1 ... Hn, and when inserting or retrieving an item from
>   the hash table, initially the H1 hash function is used. If this leads
>   to a collision, H2 is tried instead, and onwards up to Hn if needed.
>   The previous section showed only one hash function, which is the
>   initial hash function (H1). The other hash functions are very similar
>   to this function, only differentiating by a multiplicative factor. In
>   general, the hash function Hk is defined as:
>
> Hk(key) = [GetHash(key) + k * (1 + (((GetHash(key) >> 5) + 1) %
>   (hashsize – 1)))] % hashsize

However, taking the example from the MSDN site1:

```
private static Hashtable employees = new Hashtable();

public static void Main()
{
    // Add some values to the Hashtable, indexed by a string key
    employees.Add("111-22-3333", "Scott");
    employees.Add("222-33-4444", "Sam");
}
```

Let's assume that adding the second key will result in a collision, so H2 will have to be used. However, when I call employees["222-33-4444"], how does the hashtable know to use H2? Is there a separate mapping? Thanks.

Comment: If you reference a link, you should include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hash tables store both the key and the value in the hash table itself. This way later on during operations such as hash table look-ups it can be guaranteed that the value found is the one that matches the index used for the look-up. Hash tables use a simple "try the basic method of look-up until success" methodology. In this case, the method of look-up is "use hash function X" where X changes on failure.

In other schemes, the method of look-up is "look at the table entry X" (as determined by a hash function) where X just increases by one in a wrapping manner each failure.

The nagging question now is what happens when the value ISN'T in the table? Well, that can be rather ugly: When you've either hit an entry in the table which is missing or, even worse, when you've iterated through as many entries as are stored in the table, you can be sure the entry isn't there -- but that can take "a while" in the worst case.

Keep in mind that since only one value can be associated with one key, once you've found the key, you've found the value. The worst a hash table can do is having to do the equivalent of a cache-unfriendly linear search over all the values in the hash table itself... but ultimately, it will find the value if it's there because it's comparing the stored key to the requested key to test if it's there. The only optimization closed hash tables make is where to look first -- in this case, where hash function 1 says, and then 2, and then 3...

Comment: When you are referring to 'value', I assume you are referring to what is really my 'key' ("222-33-4444")? i.e. your 'key' is the hash key, and the value is "222-33-4444" which is just an abstraction of the hash key?

Comment: The `Hashtable` class uses a count to indicate how many hash collisions there have been on a given initial hash code; this prevents it from checking non-empty buckets that hold keys with different initial hash code values.

Comment: @user981225: "111-22-3333" would be the 'key' and "Scott" would be the value in my way of putting it. I was just trying to make it clear that not only the "value" is stored -- so it can indeed check to make sure that the index it finds is the one you requested.

Comment: @phoog: Interesting to know! However, I will add that if I understand correctly, it will still sometimes check non-empty buckets that hold keys with only different initial hash code values, but this can only occur when entries are removed from the table.

Answer (score 4):

<s>I think you misunderstand rehashing.  There's only one hash function: the virtual `object.GetHashCode()` (or, if you supply an IHashCodeProvider or IEqualityComparer, it uses that object to calculate the hash code).  When the hash table is full, it expands its capacity and redistributes the elements over the new, larger arrays.  The private method that does this is called `Rehash()`, but it doesn't recalculate hash codes.</s>

CORRECTION

The rehashing does not use a new function, but rather operates on the preceding value of the hash code; this has the effect of searching subsequent slots until an empty one is found (for insert/set) or until all keys with the same (initial) hash code have been checked for equality with the index key (for retrieval).

EDIT

To answer your question directly:

> Let's assume that adding the second key will result in a collision, so H2 will have to be used. However, when I call employees["222-33-4444"], how does the hashtable know to use H2? Is there a separate mapping? Thanks.

1. Calculate the correct bucket based on the hash code of the passed key.
2. If that bucket is empty, fail.
3. If the bucket's key matches the passed key, return the bucket's value.
4. If the hash collision count is zero, fail.
5. Calculate the next hash code from the current hash code.
6. Calculate the correct bucket based on the new hash code.
7. Go to step 2.

Comment: in fact `Hashtable` does use multiple hash functions, see updated question with quote, your answer is incorrect for that reason.

Comment: @BrokenGlass I doubt very much that any hash apart from `GetHashCode()` is used. The bucket calculation from this may be done in multiple ways to resolve collision of bucket indices, but it's pretty much impossible to do anything about full hash code collisions.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: That's what the MSDN link says - keep in mind that is for the pre- generics Hashtable only

Comment: @BrokenGlass I have corrected the answer after reviewing the decompiled `HashTable` class.  The incorrect information was based on my greater familiarity with the hashtable implementation of `Dictionary<K, V>` and `HashSet<T>`, which is somewhat different.

Answer (score 0):

It will first try H1. If it does not find a match, it will use H2. And so on.